# How can I show user's first name to the user after the user logged in

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I am using Ion_Auth and I have a problem. I have looked for the solution but there is no progress yet.

As an example, there is a user and his name is Alex.

When Alex is logged in the portal, He should see his name Alex and then if he clicked his name, he will go to his user settings to edit his details. The problem is I can't show the first_name when a user have logged in.

How can I do that? I don't know what codes I can publish for this situation. Tell me what you need as code, I can publish if you need.

Comment: as ion auth save user id,username and identity(email) column in session  create a user model and pass user id to it and get user first name from it $this->user->getFirstName($this->session->userdata('user_id')); that you can use for your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is:

```
$user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
echo $user->first_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Having never used Ion_Auth, I decided to have a look at the repository on GitHub. You could use the user_id and pass this to a model method to get the first name (like umefarooq has suggested).

However, I would pull the first name from the database and store it in the session when the user logs in. This means you don't have to go back to the database just to get their name.

You can see in the Ion_auth model, this line;

```
        $query = $this->db->select($this->identity_column . ', username, email, id, password, active, last_login')
```

https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/2/models/ion_auth_model.php#L985

You could just add the first name row to this query, and it will be added to the session when the user logs in.

You can then access it by:

```
$this->session->userdata('FirstName');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: means he will edit the core model, but when ever an update come for ion auth that custom editing will go, he also need to change set_session method also where he need to put session data FirstName. better way is create model get first name add in session after successful login before redirect.

Comment: You're right +1, I didn't see the "set_session" method. Personally, I would still edit these files (don't though, unless you're confident enough to do so), it's only system files I don't edit.

Comment: I have just used $this->session->userdata('FirstName'); code in my view file and then It worked. Do you think is it okey?

Comment: It should be fine, Bari. Although as @umefarooq points out, this could cause problems if you plan to upgrade Ion_auth in the future.

Comment: So, let's see. Thanks Craig. You' re so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When the user logged in successfully, store his/her first name into the session variable.

then call the specific session variable on where you want to display.